# How to access current location in reducer (redux-router)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, router

How would i get the current path and query of the current location with redux-router in reducer. I am able to get the pathname easily inside the component with mapStateToProps, but i want to access the current path in reducer. I am using redux-router 1.0.0-beta7, react-router 1.0.3.

Comment: maybe you can pass pathname into reducer through action creater?

Comment: Why would you duplicate the "source of truth" of the current path? If you need access to the current path, just get it from `props` since `router` is automatically passed. Router is the source of truth for route location, no need to duplicate this in redux. If you need to hear it from the author Redux, watch this: https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-filtering-redux-state-with-react-router-params

Comment: this is how [redux-router](https://github.com/acdlite/redux-router#differences-with-react-router-redux) works

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**1**.way - pass **pathname** with particular **action** through **[redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk)** and getState()

```
const someAction = data =>(dispatch,getState)=>{
   dispatch({
      type:'SOME_ACTION',
      pathname:getState().router.pathname
   })
}
```

**2**.way - write middleware and pass **pathname** with every action

```
///write middleware
export const attachPathNameToAction = store => next => action=>{
    action.pathname = store.getState().router.pathname //<-----passing pathname
    next(action)
};


///then in reducer you allways can get pathname
case 'SOME_ACTION':
    let pathname = action.pathname \\  <-------------
    return {...state, action.data}
```

**3**.way - pass pathname from component's this.props.location.pathname

```
//in component 
let {pathname}= this.props.location;
this.props.someAction(data, pathname);

//workflow:  component -> action -> reducer
```

Comment: The middleware solution is great! Thanks for that.
I really wonder why they don't have a plugin for it.

Comment: Note that it's `... .router.location.pathname`, not `... .router.pathname`.