# Retrieve parameters from react-router in Redux reducer

Tags: redux, react-router, react-router-redux

**I am trying to change a URL parameter when an action is dispatched. It links to the next "case" in an experiment and is presented as an integer in the URL.**

How I imagine this:
Initial URL `/experiment/2`
Dispatched Action `{ type: 'NEXT_CASE' }`
New URL `/experiment/3`

**Research**
Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38084701/2525299) (although about `redux-router`) I got the idea that I could retrieve the current path / URL in a reducer by accessing `store.getState().routing`.

But I want the parameters, as defined and parsed in my routes. (I obviously could parse them manually from the path but that doesn't seem scalable and not future-proof if the path structure changes.)

**Current solution**
My best attempt so far, based on [match](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#match-routes-location-history-options--cb) (which they say is not intended for client-side usage):

```
export default store => next => (action:Action<any>) => {
  if (action.type == Types.NEXT_CASE) {
    match(
      { routes: Routes, location: store.getState().routing.locationBeforeTransitions.pathname },
      (error, redirectLocation, renderProps: any) => browserHistory.push(RouteBuilder.experiment(parseInt(renderProps.params.caseIndex) + 1))
    );
  }

  return next(action);
}
```

Where `Routes` and `RouteBuilder` are defined as follows:

```
export const RouteBuilder = {
  experiment: (caseIndex: number) => `/experiment/${ caseIndex }`
};

export const Routes = (
  <Route path="/" component={ Root }>
    <IndexRoute component={ Welcome } />
    <Route path="experiment/:caseIndex" component={ Experiment } />
  </Route>
);
```

**Question**
Is there any straightforward way to retrieve the current route's (parsed and named) parameters in a reducer?

Comment: my answer was about redux-router. And  redux-router can give you that abillity. (getState().router.params)

Comment: Thanks, I had actually missed that difference. Updated the question to reflect the difference and will definitely consider using `redux-router`. But the question how to do this with the "regular" `react-router`/`react-router-redux` combo remains relevant, I think.